# the name 'imagePdfDocument' does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer

Why I am getting the error "the name 'imagePdfDocument' does not exist in current context."
Can anyone tell me how to fix it and why is this error message showing..
Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using C1.Win.C1Tile;
using System.Diagnostics;

private void _exportImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
            foreach (Tile tile in _imageTileControl.Groups[0].Tiles)
            {
                if (tile.Checked)
                {
                    images.Add(tile.Image);
                }
            }
            ConvertToPdf(images);
            SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFile.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            saveFile.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf*";

            if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                imagePdfDocument.Save(saveFile.FileName);

            }
        }

private void ConvertToPdf(List<Image> images)
        {
            RectangleF rect = imagePdfDocument.PageRectangle;
            bool firstPage = true;
            foreach (var selectedimg in images)
            {
                if (!firstPage)
                {
                    imagePdfDocument.NewPage();
                }
                firstPage = false;
                rect.Inflate(-72, -72);`enter code here`
                imagePdfDocument.DrawImage(selectedimg, rect);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Variable `imagePdfDocument` didn't declared at `_exportImage_Click` and `ConvertToPdf` scopes.

Comment: Did you copy paste this code from somewhere?

Comment: @SergeyNazarov can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes..

Comment: You might want to check at the place where you copied code from if you missed something to copy.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sir I have already checked.

Comment: `imagePdfDocument` this variable is not declared and initialized that's why you are getting this error. We don't why you have written or copy pasted this code, so we don't know what is the type of this variable. It's very little we can help here. Only hint is you need to declare this variable at the Form level.

Comment: You have no namespace and no class surrounding your functions. So this won't compile even if `imagePdfDocment` was defined (which it isn't.). This code piece is probably one of many snippets from some sort of tutorial. You have to get all relevant parts.

Comment: What is imagePdfDocument ? A control on the form ?

Answer (score 0):

Look what you have to do..... go to reference option of your project and uninstall the one which are identical, there may be same reference with different version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).